# Step on Hopf-Rinow via regularity.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

On a step of proving (geodesics defined for all time)=>(for any $p,q$ there exists a minimizing geodesic connecting both), besides the traditional approach of taking smooth curves $c_n$ such that $L(c_n) \to d(p,q)$, [Sakai](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821802844) mentions that one can use Arzela-Ascoli (changing the assumption of geodesics converging for all time to bounded closed balls being compact) to show that there exists a subsequence of those curves converging to a continuous path $c$. By continuity, we have that this path is length-minimizing. **Therefore, it is a geodesic**. However, I feel that the result that a continuous length-minimizing path must be a geodesic via the series of exercises and lemmata which are mentioned is very technical and kind of goes against the purpose of the argument of being cleaner.

My question is: is there a way to make a shortcut here via some regularity theorem? For example, maybe arrive somehow at the fact that the limit is a weak solution to the geodesic equation and therefore must be smooth? (I don't know any references which approch the subject in this way*, so this would be nice too, if possible).

*Except [Klingenberg's](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540083936), but his intentions are others.

Comment: One issue you should be aware of is that most regularity theorems (as well as AA theorem!) require the target space to be metrically complete, and completeness is one of the equivalent statements in HR theorem. Thus, depending on how your intended proof goes, you may have to prove that indefinite extension of geodesics implies completeness **before** proving that any two points are connected by a minimizing geodesic.  Also, proving that the limit of nearly-minimizers is a minimizer is much simpler than any elliptic regularity theorem you are planning to invoke.